# Gráficos em painéis no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Eu tenho 25 espécies e gostaria de

1. escrever apenas um script em que eu poderia ter um gráfico separado para cada espécie (no total seriam 25 pequenos gráficos, num grid 5x5).
2. Eu também gostaria de fazer dois plots diferentes para a savana e floresta;
3. colocar uma linha de tendência ligando a média dos plots (veja um exemplo na figura 2).

Alguém poderia me ajudar com o meu script? a figura 1 é o gráfico que fiz no R com o script que segue no link abaixo e a figura 2 é um exemplo do que eu gostaria de fazer.

Meus dados e script podem ser acessados pelo link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UBHOY6KdIu3SmxJRnK374rTsmYQCd5GK

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure2]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Brasil! As perguntas deste site devem, obrigatoriamente, estar em português.

Comment: @MarcusNunes StackOverflow *Brasil*? eu pensava que era StackOverflow *em português* :).

Comment: E é em português mesmo. Eu que não prestei atenção e assumi que, se escrevo em **português** (idioma vindo originalmente de **Portugal**), quem vai me ler é brasileiro. Desculpe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu tenho uma sugestão de gráfico logo abaixo. Vou postar meu código, o resultado obtido e a seguir fazer alguns comentários:

```
library(ggplot2)

dados <- read.table(file="data_fran.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE)

dados$warfare <- factor(dados$warfare, levels=c("War1", "War2", "aPost"))

ggplot(dados, aes(x=warfare, y=Abund, group=warfare:habitat_F_S, fill=habitat_F_S)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line", lwd=1, 
    aes(group=habitat_F_S, colour=habitat_F_S)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Binomial, nrow=5) +
  labs(x="Guerra", y="Abundância", colour="Habitat", fill="Habitat") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora vou dar as explicações e justificativas para este gráfico:

- `ggplot(dados, aes(x=warfare, y=Abund, group=warfare:habitat_F_S, fill=habitat_F_S))`: determina qual conjunto de dados será plotado, bem como os eixos x e y e as cores. Além disso, criei a interação `warfare:habitat_F_S,` para que os dados fossem agrupados por `warfare` e `habitat_F_S` simultaneamente
- `geom_boxplot()`: defini que queria um boxplot
- `stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line", lwd=1, aes(group=habitat_F_S, colour=habitat_F_S))`: uni as medianas dos boxplots, não as médias. Particularmente, acho que fica melhor assim, pois a linha horizontal no meio do boxplot é a mediana. Caso tu faça questão que seja a média, como pedido na pergunta, altere `fun.y=median` para `fun.y=mean`.
- `facet_wrap(~ Binomial, nrow=5)`: este é o comando que cria o grid com 5 linhas para cada espécie
- `labs(x="Guerra", y="Abundância", colour="Habitat", fill="Habitat")`: alterei os nomes dos eixos e legenda para ficarem mais explicativos
- `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))`: rotacionei os labels do eixo x em 45 graus por questões estéticas

Comment: Marcus! Muitíssimo obrigada, mesmo!!!! O script ficou ótimo bem como toda a explicação!!

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma! Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.

Comment: Ajudou muito! Aceito e votado! :)

Comment: Marcus, gostaria de tirar mais uma dúvida.

Adaptei seu script para mais algumas coisas que eu queria (ele segue no próximo comentário). Contudo, gostaria de fazer outras duas modificações, mas não estou conseguindo. São estas:

1- deixar um espaço entre os boxsplot verde (F) e laranja (s)
2-colocar o ponto referente a mediana no centro de cada boxplot (alguns pontos estão aparecendo na divisa entre os dois boxplot

Você sabe quais alterações são necessárias?

Comment: dados$warfare <- factor(dados$warfare, levels=c("war1", "war2", "Post")) 
ggplot(dados, aes(x=warfare, y=Abund, group=warfare:habitat_F_S, colour = as.factor(habitat_F_S), fill=habitat_F_S)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") + scale_colour_brewer(palette="Dark2") +

Comment: stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line", lwd=1, 
               aes(group=habitat_F_S, colour=habitat_F_S)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, colour="black", geom="point", 
               shape=18, size=1,show_guide = FALSE, aes(group=habitat_F_S, colour=habitat_F_S)) +
  facet_wrap(~ specie, nrow=5) +
  labs(x="Guerra", y="Abundância", colour="Habitat", fill="Habitat") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))